# ng-repeat - copy of objects rather than direct reference

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I want the object from ng-repeat to be a copy of the actual object in the list, how would I do so?

For example:

```
<div ng-repeat="thing in model.things">
    <input ng-model="thing.field"/>
    <button> // clicking this button would update that thing </button>
</div>
```

If I type in that input field, it will directly modify the object inside model.things. I would like it to modify a copy of the thing, and then only update the actual one when I click an update button.

I tried doing something like model.getThings() which will angular.copy() the list, but that triggers an infinite loop of $digest when a new thing is added.

How is this best done? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a plnkr for the solution that you are looking for. Please find it here https://plnkr.co/edit/MgDroW3e6hqkg2LNAtik?p=preview

**Controller**

```
$scope.data = [
  {name: 'Perry'},
  {name: 'Sam'},
  {name: 'Ron'}
];
$scope.cloned = angular.copy($scope.data);
$scope.update = function () {
  $scope.data = angular.copy($scope.cloned);
}
```

It clones the actual data and uses it in ng-repeat. And upon update it assigns back the copy of the changed data to your original data.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy your original object on initialization:

```
function YourController() {
    $scope.copyModel = angular.copy(model);
    // ...
}
```

And use copyModel in your ng-repeat

Comment: Yes but by doing that, you will overwrite every change that are done on the copy

Comment: Yes, you should: you copy copyModel back to model on click on update button.

Comment: I do not see the point to copy the final list again after clicking update button, shouldn't it be already updated (the copy list)